# How can I optimize this for loop that finds session duration in clickstreams?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, data-science

I'm a beginner in Python Data Science and I’m doing clickstream analysis. My file size is too large- around 33 million rows. I'm running this script I made to find the session duration. I'm printing i to find the progress of the operation. However close to 12 hours have passed and i has only reached till 400 000. It has close to 9 million sessions. With this speed it will take close to 270 hours(11 days). I need to optimize this to reduce the time.

Here is the dataset:

```
             Sid                    Tstamp     Itemid
0              1  2014-04-07T10:54:09.868Z  214536500
1              1  2014-04-07T10:54:46.998Z  214536506
2              1  2014-04-07T10:57:00.306Z  214577561
3              2  2014-04-07T13:56:37.614Z  214662742
4              2  2014-04-07T13:57:19.373Z  214662742
5              2  2014-04-07T13:58:37.446Z  214825110
6              2  2014-04-07T13:59:50.710Z  214757390
7              2  2014-04-07T14:00:38.247Z  214757407
8              2  2014-04-07T14:02:36.889Z  214551617
```

Here is my code. I think the for loop is slowing down the operation. For session duration I'm first finding max and min timestamps in every session. Then in for loop I'm converting them to seconds.microseconds and then final subtraction with simultaneous update in the Tstamp column.

```
adi = "H:/excelfiles/clicks3.csv"
k = pandas.read_csv(adi)

k.columns=['Sid','Tstamp','Itemid']

#Dropping Redundant Columns
k.drop(k.columns[2],axis=1,inplace=True)

#Stores max timestamp in amax
idx=k.groupby(['Sid'])['Tstamp'].transform(max) == k['Tstamp']
amax=k[idx].set_index('Sid')

#Stores min timestamp in amin
idy=k.groupby(['Sid'])['Tstamp'].transform(min) == k['Tstamp']
amin=k[idy].set_index('Sid')

i=0
for temp1,temp2,temp3 in zip(amax['Tstamp'],amax.index,amin['Tstamp']):
    sv1= datetime.datetime.strptime(temp1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    sv2= datetime.datetime.strptime(temp3, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    if(i%1000==0):    
        print i
    d1=time.mktime(sv1.timetuple()) + (sv1.microsecond / 1000000.0)
    d2=time.mktime(sv2.timetuple()) + (sv2.microsecond / 1000000.0)
    amax.loc[temp2,'duration']= (d1-d2)/60   
    i=i+1

#amax stores the final session duration
amax=amax.reset_index()
```

What could be done to optimize this code.

EDIT 1: Removed the microseconds part.

Comment: @YOU I was trying to keep the accuracy as high as possible. Since I'm eventually converting in minutes, I can remove the microseconds part.

Comment: In the past, i've found strptime to be a very expensive operation.  I would consider having pandas handling the timestamp directly.  Pandas has  pretty robust timestamp IIRC.

Comment: @YOU I'm using Anaconda/Spyder IDE for Python

Comment: @YOU Your answer seems to have been deleted. Can you share it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty easy way using standard pandas methods.  All you really have to do is convert 'Tstamp' to a pandas datetime and then take the difference of the max and min.  Since it's a datetime, the difference is automatically a time delta.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> k['Tstamp'] = pd.to_datetime( k['Tstamp'] ) 

>>> duration = ( k.groupby('Sid')['Tstamp'].max() 
               - k.groupby('Sid')['Tstamp'].min() )

Sid
1   00:02:50.438000
2   00:05:59.275000
Name: Tstamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you can ignore microseconds or milliseconds part, you can try my module called **[mktime](https://github.com/S-YOU/mktime)**.

To Install it

```
pip install mktime
```

Usage

```
import mktime
mktime.mktime("2014-04-07T10:54:09.868Z")
# 1396868049
```

Performance test

```
% cat test.py
from mktime import mktime
import datetime
import time

temp1 = "2014-04-07T10:54:09.868Z"

def test1():
    sv1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    d1=time.mktime(sv1.timetuple()) + (sv1.microsecond / 1000000.0)
    #print d1

def test2():
    d1 = mktime(temp1)
    #print d1
```

Result (**100** times faster in my machine)

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import test' 'test.test1()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 20 usec per loop
% python -m timeit -s 'import test' 'test.test2()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.199 usec per loop
```

You can also use [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for loop if you have millions, that don't have allocate the whole list in memory.

Something like this

```
from mktime import mktime
from itertools import izip

i = 0
for temp1,temp2,temp3 in izip(amax['Tstamp'],amax.index,amin['Tstamp']):
    if(i%1000==0):    
        print i
    amax.loc[temp2,'duration']= (mktime(temp1) - mktime(temp3)) / 60.0
    i=i+1
```